# Colour space conversion from yuv44416le to yuv420p10le using ffmpeg command line tool

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to convert from yuv444 planar 16 bit little-endian format to yuv420 planar 10 bit little-endian format using ffmpeg?

I have tried the following command but failed:

```
ffmpeg -y -pixel_format yuv444p16le -s 4096x4096 -r 30 -i input.yuv -pixel_format yuv420p10le -s 4096x4096 -r 30 output.yuv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -pixel_format yuv444p16le -s 4096x4096 -framerate 30 -i input.yuv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le output.yuv
```

`-pixel_format` is an input option for raw demuxers.

`-pix_fmt` is an output option for the target format.

Note that 10 bit formats are still padded to 16-bit,so storage size will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you. Works flawlessly. I misread the distinction between pixel_format and pix_fmt.